# Get back to square one

Tags: ios, tableview, ibaction

In this little app I start out on a tableview. The user clicks one of the cells and a video starts playing.  Once the video is finished the view changes to a small test, and when the test is finished I do a partial page curl to show the result.

All working great thanks to so many here that has helped out.

Now to the question;
On the last page with the result I have a button "Done". I would like once that is clicked go straight back to the first table view so it's ready for the next video.  Is it possible?

The button has a IBAction.

Answer (score 0):

if u got a navigation controller managing you app navigation, use popToRoot.
If u don't you should add one. It will greatly simplify things.

Comment: I have a Tab Bar, but it is hidden in the two test windows.  I would just want to get straight back to the start window with the Tab Bat back.  If I use popToRoot, how do I use it with my button?

Comment: Tab based is good as well. You can select any tab u wish to be displayed programatically.

Comment: each item on the tab is associated to a view controller. This is how apple intended the use of of UITabBarController. When u wish to display a specific tab, use the selectedItem property to change the selected tab. Take a look over UITabBarController documentation on develope.apple.com